# Miktex xetex-def package installation

Tags: xetex, miktex, ctan

Miktex wants to install xetex-def package in order to compile. It cannot be installed automatically from package depository because of server error (error response from server:404).
Package files can be downloaded from http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xetex-def. Though I haven't found any package documentation with installation instructions.
After downloaded from CTAN, there are just .def files. Where to put them?

Comment: There was a recent reorganisation for the graphic drivers, and `xetex-def` is obsolete. Install the new `graphics-def`.

Comment: I downloaded multiple .def files (xetex.def, pdftex.def, luatex.def...) in graphics-def folder. What do you mean by graphics-def package? The question about installation .def files stays unanswered.

Comment: Put the whole folder in `MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex` and refresh the FNDB (both as Admin and as User). Christian Schenk removed the older versions, buts seems to have forgotten to add this package. I guess it will be in the next update.

Comment: I'm sorry to have given you a wrong information: I've just checked: it's in the last update (6/7/2016). So use MiKTeX PackageManager.

Comment: Synchronize your offline package database (package manager + package manager admin, menu repositories). Then miktex will know about the new location. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388

Comment: Thank you, after db synchronization I found out 'graphics-def' package in the list of packages :)

Comment: Install graphics-def AND graphics-cfg. The later is not installed on the fly and I went nuts after installing graphics-def. Install graphics-cfg and you are set.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin)` synchronize your packages which has installed after you finished the installation of `basic-miktex.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Based on what others said I thought it isn't problem with `graphics-def` package, or with `xetex-def` file, but with those that use them.

What worked for me was:

- Make sure you have `graphics-def` package via **MiKTeX Package Manager**.
- Make sure you have other packages, e.g. `fontspec` and xetex related, up-to-date via **Update MiKTeX (Admin)**.

Sorry for not being too specific on these updated packages, because I went crazy and updated all I was using. (Side recommendation: update all packages.)

Comment: I synchronized and updated everything. Miktex package manager does not have xetex-def but still get the error "xeted-def not found" from graphics.sty

Comment: @Echeban this error shows up when you have old version of something that depends on xetex-def, even though you don't use it. My suggestion is to update one-by-one every package you include in your tex. Then refresh editor or even pc.