# Hebrew with XeLaTeX Problem

Tags: xetex, texstudio, hebrew

I'm attempting to test out the use of Hebrew text using XeLaTeX in TeXstudio, with Guy Rutenberg's example code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\setmonofont{Miriam Mono CLM}
\setsansfont{Simple CLM}
% Use the following if you only want to change the font for Hebrew
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}

\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
טקסט רגיל
\textbf{טקסט מודגש}
\textit{טקסט נטוי}
\textit{\textbf{טקסט מודגש ונטוי}}
בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ:

\begin{english}
In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
\end{english}

\sffamily
טקסט רגיל
\textbf{טקסט מודגש}
\textit{טקסט נטוי}
\textit{\textbf{טקסט מודגש ונטוי}}
בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ:

\begin{english}
In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
\end{english}

\ttfamily
טקסט רגיל
\textbf{טקסט מודגש}
\textit{טקסט נטוי}
\textit{\textbf{טקסט מודגש ונטוי}}
בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ:

\begin{english}
In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

However, when I compile, I'm prompted for a package installation:

[image]

And, when proceeding with this installation, I receive the following error during compilation:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `xetex.def' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: def)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > ...d{ver@\Gin@driver}{\input{\Gin@driver}}{}
```

I've synchronized the MiKTeX Package Manager in both admin and user modes, but this error still persists.  Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

**EDIT 1 (8/7/2016 10:24PM)**

Here's a screencap of the xetex.def installation from MiKTeX Package Manager:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Did you get any errors when you installed? Does it show as installed? What does `kpsewhich xetex.def` give? Don't use the `minimal` class - it is not suitable, even for minimal examples, as it is not designed for this. You don't need to load `fontspec` or `bidi` as `polyglossia` will do it.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't get any errors when installing the graphics-def package containing xetex.def, and I've included a screencap of the installation status in an edit above (in case I'm missing something there).  I also changed the `minimal` class to `book` and commended out the `fontspec` and `bidi` packages, but I'm still getting the same prompt to install xetex.def, and then the same message showing the installation failure.

Comment: But does `kpsewhich` find it? And did you install for user also? Because when you compile, it can't be found. So something is screwy somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you.  Running `kpsewhich xetex.def` produces the same prompt I screencapped above from when I try to compile.  And, yes, I did install for all users.

Comment: That's odd. It shouldn't give an error or a prompt. It should just return nothing, I think. Unless it is different on MikTeX, which I've never used.

Answer (score 1):

About xetex.def, see previews answer here: [Miktex xetex-def package installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319150/miktex-xetex-def-package-installation).

The following MWE works for me with MacTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Frank Ruehl CLM}

\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\noindent
טקסט רגיל
\textit{טקסט נטוי}
\textbf{טקסט מודגש}
\textit{\textbf{טקסט מודגש ונטוי}} % Keep on empty line below

\begin{english}
In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
\end{english} % Keep on empty line below

\noindent
בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ: \\
\textit{בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ:} \\
\textbf{בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ:} \\
\textit{\textbf{בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ:}} % Keep on empty line below

\begin{english}
In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
\end{english}
\end{document}
```